# Select Dropdown Passing undefined value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here I have Checked "Samsung Galaxy S6" in that checkbox list .one dropdown is coming after checked Samsung Galaxy S6 .if select 20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6 in that drop down after submit i should get 20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6 offer id de34575.here i am getting undefined value .i have added my code below.[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/7/)

```js
function Test1Controller($scope) {
  var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
    var serverData = ["Samsung Galaxy Note", "Samsung Galaxy S6", "Samsung Galaxy Avant","Samsung Galaxy Young"];
    $scope.items= [] ;

    for(var i=0;i<serverData.length;i++)
    {
        var modal = {
        name:serverData[i],
        selected:false
        };        
        $scope.items.push(modal);        
    }
    //----------------------------Our Shop Offers----------------------------------------
    $scope.offers = [
    {
        id: "as23456",
        Store: "samsung",
        Offer_message:"1500rs off",
        modalname: "Samsung Galaxy Young"       

    },{
        id: "de34575",
        Store: "samsung",
        Offer_message:"20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6",
        modalname: "Samsung Galaxy S6"       

    },
    ]
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     $scope.check = function()
  
     {
  console.log($scope.Offer);
  
         var checkedItems = [];
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++)
            {
                  if($scope.items[i].selected){
                      checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
                    }
            }
              console.log(checkedItems) ; 
     }
$scope.selection = [];

      $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(item) {
$scope.gotOffers=[];
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(item);

      // is currently selected
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      // is newly selected
      else {
        $scope.selection.push(item);
      }

        for(var i=0;i<$scope.selection.length;i++){
          for(var j=0;j<$scope.offers.length;j++){
            console.log($scope.selection[i].name  +"   "+ $scope.offers[j].modalname)
            if( $scope.selection[i].name  == $scope.offers[j].modalname){
              var idx = $scope.gotOffers.indexOf($scope.offers[j].Offer_message);
              if(idx == -1){
                console.log("inside idx")
                $scope.gotOffers.push($scope.offers[j].Offer_message);
              }

            }
          }

        }
  
    };


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Test1Controller" >
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"  ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)"/> {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <select ng-show="gotOffers.length > 0" ng-model="offer">
      <option ng-repeat="offer in gotOffers"  ng-value="offer.id">{{offer}}</option>
    </select>

      <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Angular**

```
function Test1Controller($scope) {
  var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
    var serverData = ["Samsung Galaxy Note", "Samsung Galaxy S6", "Samsung Galaxy Avant","Samsung Galaxy Young"];
    $scope.items= [] ;

    for(var i=0;i<serverData.length;i++)
    {
        var modal = {
        name:serverData[i],
        selected:false
        };        
        $scope.items.push(modal);        
    }
    //----------------------------Our Shop Offers----------------------------------------
    $scope.offers = [
    {
        id: "as23456",
        Store: "samsung",
        Offer_message:"1500rs off",
        modalname: "Samsung Galaxy Young"       

    },{
        id: "de34575",
        Store: "samsung",
        Offer_message:"20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6",
        modalname: "Samsung Galaxy S6"       

    },
    ]
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     $scope.check = function()

     {


         var checkedItems = [];
         console.log($scope.offerSelected)
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++)
            {
                  if($scope.items[i].selected){
                      checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
                    }
            }
              console.log(checkedItems) ; 
     }
$scope.selection = [];

      $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(item) {
$scope.gotOffers=[];
      var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(item);

      // is currently selected
      if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      // is newly selected
      else {
        $scope.selection.push(item);
      }

        for(var i=0;i<$scope.selection.length;i++){
          for(var j=0;j<$scope.offers.length;j++){
            console.log($scope.selection[i].name  +"   "+ $scope.offers[j].modalname)
            if( $scope.selection[i].name  == $scope.offers[j].modalname){
              var idx = $scope.gotOffers.indexOf($scope.offers[j].Offer_message);
              if(idx == -1){
                console.log("inside idx")
                $scope.gotOffers.push($scope.offers[j]);
              }

            }
          }

        }
        console.log($scope.offers);

    };


}
```

**Html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Test1Controller" >
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected"  ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)"/> {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <select ng-show="gotOffers.length > 0" ng-model="offerSelected">
      <option ng-repeat="offer in gotOffers"  value="{{offer.id}}">{{offer.Offer_message}}</option>
    </select>

      <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/9/)

Also refer [angular-select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

**Explaination**

1. Push the whole `offer` object instead of only the `Offer_message` in `gotOffers` array to extract the id.
2. `ng-model` should be on the `select` tag and not in the `option` tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/12/ .check that fiddle .assume if i already selected Samsung Galaxy S6 .so i have pused to checkbox like this var selectedvalue="Samsung Galaxy S6";
    for(var i=0;i<serverData.length;i++)
    {
        var modal = {
        name:serverData[i],
        selected:false
        };  
  if (selectedvalue.indexOf(serverData[i]) >= 0 || null)
  {
                        modal.selected = true;

        }
        $scope.items.push(modal);        
    }.its not working when i remove ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)" .checkbox checked

Comment: It will not work when you remove ng-click="toggleSelection(item)" because your functionality for offers is based on it. Please refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/13/). Just for a suggestion why are you not using radio buttons for items instead of checkboxes??

Comment: here i want to push selected value  Samsung Galaxy S6 in check box list .http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/12/.check my fiddle

Comment: Please refer to the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/14/). I think this is what you are trying to achieve??

Comment: how to show already checked values in that check box list? check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/15/ .when i add  ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)" this line its not working   http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/16/

Comment: You donot need to add all the above functions. For already checked values, its selected property is true and while looping over the items array we are taking care of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97629/discussion-between-martin-and-sahil-gupta).

Comment: how can i push already checked values can you pls  update this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0heruyep/16/